# extract all images in icon file in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, icons, extract

I need help on how to extract the various images from an icon file ie 256 x 256, 48 x 48, 32 x 32, 24 x 24, 16 x 16 etc.

Am a vb6 and vb.net average programmer, and would be ok if help comes from any of the programming languages i mentioned

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ExctactIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648068(VS.85).aspx) or [`ExtractIconEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648069(VS.85).aspx) get [icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx) from a file, returning icon handle(s).

[`DrawIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648064(VS.85).aspx) or [`DrawIconEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648065(VS.85).aspx) draw them using the handles.
Alternatively, [`Bitmap.FromHICON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.fromhicon.aspx) in .net creates an image from an icon handle.

[`DestroyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648063(VS.85).aspx) frees resources allocated by `ExtractIcon` / `ExtractIconEx`.

Comment: The reference you gave me was for vb.net, is it possible i use this in vb6, i don't have the declaration for the api

Comment: @Smith See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071171/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-windows-api-constants-in-a-none-net-enviroment/1071406#1071406) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071171/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-windows-api-constants-in-a-none-net-enviroment).