# ExtractIconEx all icon sizes vb6 including 256

Tags: vb6, icons, extract

I need to extract all Icons sizes up to 256x256 from ico,exe,dll,icl files

ExtractIconEx only extracts 32x32 and 16x16 icons

thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045.aspx) will extract the icon with dimenstions closest to `cxDesired` and `cyDesired`.

Comment: how can i use this in vb6, please can you giv me sample code. i don't understand the api

Comment: @Smith: Use an API viewer, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071171/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-windows-api-constants-in-a-none-net-enviroment/1071406#1071406).

Answer (score 0):

A one time thing or you need this in your own program?

There's a ton of good icon extractors free out there

Here's just one

http://www.rw-designer.com/batch-icon-extractor