# What is the hex value of PROCESS_CREATION_MITIGATION_POLICY_BLOCK_NON_MICROSOFT_BINARIES_ALWAYS_ON?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I would like to use the `UpdateProcThreadAttribute()` API call in a C# program, but I can't find the hex value of `PROCESS_CREATION_MITIGATION_POLICY_BLOCK_NON_MICROSOFT_BINARIES_ALWAYS_ON`. I was only able to find `(0x00000001ui64 << 44)` on [Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-updateprocthreadattribute), but I don't know how I can implement this into my code and use it as an `IntPtr`, according to [PInvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/UpdateProcThreadAttribute.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find a list of windows API constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718975/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-windows-api-constants)

Comment: `ui64` is a C++ suffix equivalent to C#'s `UL` suffix (for `ulong`), so it's `(0x1UL << 44)`, or  `0x1000_0000_0000UL`, in C#.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, `0x00000001ui64` is an unsigned 64bit integer with a value of `1`, and `<< 44` is left-shifting that value by 44 bits. A left-shift is equivalent to multiplying by 2, so the result of multiplying `1` by `2` 44 times is `17592186044416`, which in hex is `0x100000000000UL`, or `0x1000_0000_0000UL` for readibility.

FYI, C# has the [same bit-shift operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators) that C/C++ has.

`LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` is a pointer to a `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` structure. Call [`InitializeProcThreadAttributeList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-initializeprocthreadattributelist) 1 time to determine how large that list needs to be, then allocate memory of that size, and call `InitializeProcThreadAttributeList()` again to initialize the list.

For example (also see [.NET : How to PInvoke UpdateProcThreadAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427196/)):

```cs
const int PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_MITIGATION_POLICY = 0x20007;
const long PROCESS_CREATION_MITIGATION_POLICY_BLOCK_NON_MICROSOFT_BINARIES_ALWAYS_ON = 0x100000000000L;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
     IntPtr lpAttributeList,
     int dwAttributeCount,
     int dwFlags,
     ref IntPtr lpSize);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(IntPtr lpAttributeList);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
     IntPtr lpAttributeList,
     uint dwFlags,
     IntPtr Attribute,
     IntPtr lpValue,
     IntPtr cbSize,
     IntPtr lpPreviousValue,
     IntPtr lpReturnSize);

...

IntPtr attrListSize = 0;
InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
    IntPtr.Zero,
    1,
    0,
    ref attrListSize);

IntPtr attrList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(attrListSize);
InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
    attrList,
    1,
    0,
    ref attrListSize);

IntPtr lpValue = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(long));
Marshal.WriteInt64(lpValue, PROCESS_CREATION_MITIGATION_POLICY_BLOCK_NON_MICROSOFT_BINARIES_ALWAYS_ON);

UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
    attrList,
    0,
    (IntPtr)PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_MITIGATION_POLICY,
    lpValue,
    sizeof(long),
    IntPtr.Zero,
    IntPtr.Zero
);

// use attrList as needed, ie in STARTUPINFOEX.lpAttributeList ...

DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(attrList);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpValue);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(attrList);
```